Connecting Jenkins (Docker) to Minikube Kubernetes Cluster Issue
I have Jenkins running inside a Docker container on my local machine, and I'm trying to connect it to a Minikube Kubernetes cluster also running locally. Both jenkins and minikube are using same docker network named minikube. However, I'm encountering connection issues.
When attempting to connect Kubernetes from Jenkins, I receive the error:
Error testing connection: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:50105
Tried updating Kubernetes configuration .kube/config to use minikube ip instead of 127.0.0.1.
Encountered a kubeconfig misconfigured error when checking minikube status after this change.
I expect Jenkins to successfully connect to Minikube Kubernetes without errors.
Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For this you have add first credentials for minikube config to jenkins (eg: certificates and key)
i have done this and then metion in Jenkins pipeline like this:
This is how i configure

Welcome to SO! Thanks for providing an answer, but please include the actual code (with explanation) in the answer itself, so the answer remains valuable even if the link ever breaks in the future.
